# Reusing a form with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a page with a list of things. I want the user to be able to click on an item in the list and open a modal dialog with a relatively complicated form with data for each item. I've implemented the form using Vue.js, and so far, it works, but I can't figure out how to get the Vue to switch from the data for one item to the data for another item, or do something equivalent to that.

The examples make it look like components are for small things and not entire forms. Here's the JavaScript from a JS fiddle with a hastily-coded example that's kind of similar to what I want to do.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-identifier="1">
      <td><a>Item 1</a></td>
      <td class="json">{ "id": "1", "formData": { "whichOption": "1", "optionOneSetting": "ONE AYE", "optionTwoSetting": null, "optionThreeSetting": null } }</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-identifier="2">
      <td><a>Item 2</a></td>
      <td class="json">{ "id": "2", "formData": { "whichOption": "2", "optionOneSetting": null, optionTwoSetting": "two-b", "optionThreeSetting": null } }</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-identifier="3">
      <td><a>Item 3</a></td>
      <td class="json">{ "id": "3", "formData": { "whichOption": "2", "optionOneSetting": null, "optionTwoSetting": "two-c", "optionThreeSetting": null } }</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-identifier="4">
      <td><a>Item 4</a></td>
      <td class="json">{ "id": "4", "formData": { "whichOption": "3", "optionOneSetting": null, "optionTwoSetting": null, "optionThreeSetting": "true" } }</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-identifier="5">
      <td><a>Item 5</a></td>
      <td class="json">{ "id": "5", "formData": { "whichOption": "1", "optionOneSetting": "ONE AYE AGAIN", "optionThreeSetting": null } }</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="app" class="hidden">
  <select v-model="formData.whichOption">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <label v-if="formData.whichOption==1">1-A: <input type="text" v-model="formData.optionOneSetting" /></label>
  <div v-if="formData.whichOption==2">
    <label><input type="radio" name="optionTwoSetting" value="two-a" v-model="formData.optionTwoSetting" /> 2-A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="optionTwoSetting" value="two-b" v-model="formData.optionTwoSetting" /> 2-B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="optionTwoSetting" value="two-c" v-model="formData.optionTwoSetting" /> 2-C</label>
  </div>
  <div v-if="formData.whichOption==3">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="optionThreeSetting" value="three" v-model="formData.optionThreeSetting" /> 3-A</label>
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="doMagic">Do a Thing</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var data = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.json").text();
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        if (!document.vue) {
            document.vue = new Vue({
                el: "#app"
              , data: data
              , methods: {
                    doMagic: function(event) {
                        var $tr = $("tr[data-identifier=" + this.id + "]");
                         console.log($.extend({}, this));

                         $tr.find(".json").text(JSON.stringify({
                             "id": this.id
                           , "formData": this.formData
                         }));
                    }
                 }
            })
            $("#app").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else {
            // This isn't expected to work, but it's effectively what I'd like to happen.
            document.vue.data = data;
        }
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/don01001100/eywraw8t/370396/

Comment: Components can be as big or small as you want them to be. In fact, component composition (components in components) is a highly recommended approach

Comment: Thanks, @Phil. None of the examples on the Vue.js site quite seem to do something similar to what asked, which leads me to be leave my question isn't well-informed. Looking at the problem with an eye to components as a solution, it seems that the entire page (or, rather, the smallest DOM element that contains everything) should be the Vue rather than form. Is that consistent with said highly recommended approach?